# Requirements for WEB_MESSAGE_LISTENER feature to be supported

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview, postmessage

What are the requirements for the [`WEB_MESSAGE_LISTENER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewCompat.WebMessageListener) feature to be supported? Is there a specific version of the WebView APK on the device to be met?

If the feature is not supported, could it be possible to require a minimum WebView version for the feature to be supported? We tried to look at the [Google Chrome version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) to see any indication of changes in the feature, without any luck. Recent empirical experiments we have performed indicate that WebView major version 81 is that last major version which does not support this feature, indicating that users should at least have version 82. Does anybody know whether or not this is a good approach to the problem?

Also, if we require the user to update the WebView version, is it feasible to require the app with package name `com.google.android.webview` to be updated?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question elsewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We decided to prompt the user with an update screen in case `WEB_MESSAGE_LISTENER` was not supported. The update screen sends the user to Google Play to update the WebView. If anyone else has a better solution, we sould love to hear it!